# "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",

Tags: postman

I did an exercise on the cisco curriculum using Postmant to get Host history .. there was an error message ":" Request method 'GET' not supported ", ... to practice using the post method to get a ticket / certificate has been successful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBwon.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That is because “https://sandboxapicem.cisco.com/api/v1/ticket” doesn’t exist for method GET

Check if the path is correct and there no parameters needed.
Maybe the path is something like: “https://sandboxapicem.cisco.com/api/v1/ticket/{id}”
Or
“https://sandboxapicem.cisco.com/api/v1/ticket?id={id}

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the method to `POST`

[image]